# jquery does not set element height when page is loaded directly, only when linked to by another page

Tags: jquery

Im trying to force the height of a element on one of my pages but for whatever reason the jquery Im using only works when hit the page from a link on another page. Not if you goto the site page directly or reload it. The page is here:

http://kylejenningsdesign.com/gp/

There is supposed to be a large slideshow on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
$('.imageCycler img').each(function(){
        maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
        $(this).closest('div').height($(this).height());
});
```

to

```
$('.imageCycler img').load(function(){
        maxHeight = (maxHeight > $(this).height()) ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
        $(this).closest('div').height($(this).height());
        $('.imageCycler').height(maxHeight);
});
```

This will trigger height calculations after images are all loaded.
Read more: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: Doesnt look like it works in chrome, but firefox seems to be working.

Comment: I have updated the code a bit. It might be operator precedence that is different among the two. Try it out now.

Comment: ok it kinnndaaaa works. check out this page tho and try to paginate. now the images are only like 10px tall lol

Comment: So with this last edit you should be good to go... it did need that one line.

Comment: aweeesommemmme you rule. Also, also, setting that inner div's overflow to visible worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be that the non-working version is setting the height of your image divs to 0.  You're still setting and unsetting "display:none" properly, but with 0 height, it's not helping.  I'm not quite sure *why* this is happening, but if you modify the code that sets the div visible to also set the height to something reasonable (600, say), and then do that for the first element on pageload, that should let you kludge around it.  Indeed, if you're trying to set the height and not doing it on pageload, that may be your problem.  I'm not certain why this is happening, but if I had to guess I'd say it was load order.